# Unable to access cloud function from GKE Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine

We want to secure our cloud function ( Http )  so added ingress setting to allow internal traffic
after adding we unable to communicate from Service in GKE cluster to this cloud function
Getting 403 error

I am not able to understand because they are under same project
what are the things i need to configure to access my cloud function from microservice in GKE cluster

Can you please suggest what are the configurations needs to be taken care to secure the cloud function and successful connection between the microservice in GKE and cloud function?

Comment: Does your function require authentication? How do you call your functions from GKE? How do you deploy it?

Comment: i am calling my function using a jwt token , I am generating the JWT token  from the code 
in GKE its a spring boot based micro service

Comment: Could you please share with us the documentation you are following to generate the JWT token and a code snippet?

Comment: credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();

          

            IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential =
                    IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
                            .setIdTokenProvider((IdTokenProvider) credentials)
                            .setTargetAudience(serviceUrl)
                            .build();
            authorization = tokenCredential.getRequestMetadata().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);

Answer (score 0):

Only traffic from VPC networks in the same project or the same VPC SC perimeter is allowed.

check that you cluster and could function are in the VPC by selecting the right VPC connector.

Comment: VPC connector is only for egress. No relation with ingress control.

Comment: how can i identify which vpc i am getting the trafic into my cloud function